# Eclipse 2019-06 with buildship integration: DocumentBuilder is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-platform-module-system, buildship

I have a multi-project gradle setup (settings.gradle) which I import to eclipse using OpenJDK-12.

After importing I get compile errors (on some but not all projects) like this:

`The type javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder is not accessible`

If I clean (and automatically rebuild) the project, the error goes away. If however I clean all projects, errors reappear (not necessarily the exact same errors, but all of them are of the "... not accessible" kind.

This seems like an eclipse bug to me, but if anyone has an idea what I can do to further narrow down the problem I'd be thankful.

Comment: Sometimes I have to clean the project more than once for the error to go away. Very non-deterministic behaviour.

Comment: It turns out this is a bug in eclipse which was fixed in 2019-09. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547181